# eccentricity of locus of hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

The locus of intersection of the lines $\sqrt 3 x-y-4\sqrt3 t=0$ and $\sqrt 3 tx+ty-4\sqrt 3=0$(where t is a parameter) is a hyperbola . we have to find its eccentricity .

I got the intersection point as  $x=(2+2t^2)/(t)$ and $y=(2\sqrt 3)/(2\sqrt 3 t^2 +t)$.

after that I got stuck .

Comment: I'd say the locus of intersection of two *lines* in Euclidean space $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ is either the empty space or a point. What did you actually mean here? And the second equation doesn't seem to be a line.

Comment: It is a whole _family_ of pairs of lines, so the locus of intersections can be pretty much anything.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes , locus of intersection would be hyperbola .

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, *after* the edition of the question  that $\;t\;$ is a parameter *now* that's clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The family of lines is

$$\begin{cases}&I\;\;\sqrt3\,x-y=4\sqrt3\,t\,/\,\cdot(-t)\implies-\sqrt3\,tx+ty=-4\sqrt3t^2\\{}\\
&II\;\;\sqrt3\,tx+ty=4\sqrt3\end{cases}\stackrel{\text{sum up}\,-tI+II}\implies$$

$$\;2ty=4\sqrt3(1-t^2)\implies \color{red}{y=\frac{2\sqrt3(1-t^2)}t}\stackrel{\text{substitute in I}}\implies$$

$$\sqrt3\,x=4\sqrt3\,t+\frac{2\sqrt3(1-t^2)}t\implies$$

$$ \color{red}{x=4t+\frac{2(1-t^2)}t=\frac{2(t^2+1)}t}$$

so

$$\begin{cases}&x^2=\cfrac{4(t^2+1)^2}{t^2}\\{}\\
&y^2=\cfrac{12(t^2-1)^2}{t^2}\end{cases}\implies 3x^2-y^2=48\implies\cfrac{x^2}{4^2}-\cfrac{y^2}{(4\sqrt3)^2}=1$$

and thus the eccentricity is

$$e=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}a=\frac{\sqrt{16+48}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{64}}{4}=2$$